# linq lambda expression; get EF object and remove selected properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a single instance of an object:

```
AS_SYSTEM system = ctx.AS_SYSTEM.Where(s => s.SYSTEM_ID == query).First();
```

And i want to remove some properties from it. All properties that ends with "Reference". Something like

```
system.GetType().GetProperties().Name.EndsWith("Reference")
```

I want to remove all ef properties that are linked to other tables.

Comment: Do you mean you want the properties to be null or you actually want to remove the properties entirely? The properties belong to the type and are instantiated on the instance, removing them at run time is not a trivial task..

Comment: @SeanThoman I think null is enough. I just want to avoid a circular reference while serializing the object to json using a JavaScriptSerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To nullify (the values) of all properties ending with 'Reference', using reflection:

```
var properties = system.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Reference"));

foreach (var p in properties)
{
    p.SetValue(system, null, null); 
}
```

Though I'm not sure that you really need to use reflection here, thats how its done.